# Find the first element in list. C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, list

this is my program for list implementation in C++. And want to print the first element in it.
I write element until I reach 0

Can You show me the way to do it. Thanks

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

int main()
{
    Node *first = 0;
    Node *p;

    cout << "Enter a list" << endl;
    int i;
    while (true) {
        cin >> i;
        if (i == 0) break;

        p = new Node;
        p -> data = i;

        p -> next = first ;
        first = p;
    }

    cout << "List: ";

    p = first;
    while (p) {
        cout << p -> data;
        p = p -> next;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program has a problem with keeping the initial element of the list: the code that you have assigns the *last* element to the variable called `first`, so your second loop will end as soon as it starts.

You need to change the logic around assigning `first`: for example, rather than assigning it unconditionally, you could assign it only if it is `0`:

```
if (first == 0) {
    first = p;
}
```

In addition to fixing this, you should add code to free the objects that you allocate with `new`. Use `delete` to free up the nodes in the list. This can be done in the same way as your second loop:

```
p = first;
while (p) {
    Node* tmp = p;
    p = p -> next;
    delete tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you created is a stack (LIFO). You are adding new elements to its top, so `first` actually points to the last added element when you are traversing the data structure.

So, you can traverse it till the element's `next` is NULL - that's your actual first element.

Or you can change your program to use a different data structure, where you add elements to the tail and not to the head, or where you keep a pointer to the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Just visit your linked list until you hit a node whose next pointer is 0.
This is the first node. Print its value and you are done.
Keep a pointer on the last node to be able to traverse the linked list.
If you need that first node often, keep an extra pointer for it.